# Hiding internals when returning iterators in Rust

Tags: rust

I've written a function which returns an iterator which lists all Fibonacci numbers:

```rust
fn fib<'a>() -> Unfold<'a, int, (int, int)> {
  Unfold::new((1, 1), |st| {
    let (a, b) = *st;
    *st = (b, a + b);
    Some(a)
  })
}
```

Unfortunately, the return type exposes a lot of this function's internals, such as the internal state type `(int, int)`. What are my options for hiding these internals?

Comment: Wrap Unfold in a struct that implements Iterator. There are some plans to allow `impl Iterator<T>` as return type which would be valid for any type implementing Iterator, but we aren't there yet.

Comment: What you’ve written there isn’t doing what you might think or want anyway—`'a` is `'static`.

Comment: @A.B.: Any mailing list threads/RFCs about these plans? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @reinerp, there is [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/105) but it is closed in favor of improved one which is yet to be written.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Changes in inference means that `'a` for arbitrary lifetime will infer better than `'static` anyway since this week.

Comment: @user139873 does that still apply now?

Comment: Probably not, rustc has improved a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As A.B pointed out, the standard method is to wrap it in a struct:

```rust
pub struct Fibonacci {
    inner: Unfold<'static, i32, (i32, i32)>
}

impl Iterator for Fibonacci {
    type Item = i32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        self.inner.next()
    }
}

pub fn fib() -> Fibonacci {
    Fibonacci {
        inner: Unfold::new((1, 1), |st| {
            let (a, b) = *st;
            *st = (b, a + b);
            Some(a)
        })
    }
}
```

By the way, I also fixed a few nits:

- As Chris Morgan notes, it's clearer to use `'static` as the lifetime.
- `int` (aka [`isize`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0544-rename-int-uint.md)) shouldn't be used here, as the Fibonacci sequence doesn't depend on the size of a pointer. I changed it to the more idiomatic `i32`.